# html validator versus SU:BADGE

Tags: html

How to fix that

```
element "SU:BADGE" undefined <su:badge layout="5"></su:badge>
```

I use HTML 4.01 Transitional on my website ...

The BADGE is from stumbleupon.com website

Thank you . Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since such markup is not valid in HTML 4.01, the validator is just doing what you asked it to do: reporting any reportable markup errors.

The only practical reason why such error messages might be disturbing is that if there are many of them, you might accidentally miss to notice some *other* error messages, relating to constructs where your markup *unintentionally* deviates from HTML 4.01. If this is an issue, consider writing a [custom DTD](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/own-dtd.html). It requires some understanding of SGML, but so does the use of validators in general, does it not?

On the other hand, you might decide to refrain from using tags suggested by people who cannot do such a simple thing using valid HTML. There are many ways to put information on a web page in a manner that does not affect the visible appearance but can be retrieved by programs that search for specific constructs (e.g., `meta` tags). They decided on a way that causes problems to authors who wish to use validtors.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t.

Validation is nice (especially as a sanity check while developing) but if you don’t use valid markup then there’s nothing you can do, and if you *need* invalid markup (because you use a third-party API for instance) then validation simply ceases to be relevant.

Alternatively, you could serve your page as XML instead of HTML 4 and define an appropriate `su` XML namespace. But since this would mean that some browsers no longer display your page correctly this is more a theoretical possibility.